# Linux, execve how to run a child binary and pass payload efficently?

Tags: c++, c, linux

till today when i was starting up a child program in my application (distributed computing) i used execv and as an argument i was passing a filename which has a payload stored.

So i had two files:

1) child-program.binary (+x)

2) child-program.payload (+r)

When child-program.binary executed it knew that it has to load child-program.payload on startup, then the computing took place and the new payload was stored into child-program.payload file.

i would like to change that and instead of storing payload on the hard drive, i would love to run the binary and pass the payload the different way, maybe via pipes?

Also, do i have to store the binary on the hard disk to be able to run it?
Isn't there any other memory like option to execute something?

What are the possible options?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of your file-approach is that it is non-volatile and the data can be easily distributed around the globe as file.

Based on your thought about pipes, I assume your "distributed computing" is on the same node. You could also use shared memory see: [shm_open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) and pass the name of the "file" name of your shared memory to the child.
BTW. Pipes or FIFOs let you easily synchornize using poll/select. AFAIK you need a bit more infrastructure to synchronize access to Shared Memory.

Comment: Thanks, will try shm approach.
My distributed system works on distributed nodes (see raspberry pi gridman). 

The name of the payload/binary is dynamically created when the task is spawned, therefore each task has differend filename/payload name - allowing me to run couple of workers (as per cpu core count) in the same directory.